# What is the process to plaq mount (dry mount) photos on MDF?

Tags: frames

I've seen plaq mounted photos that seem to be laminated on MDF board.  I'm interested in producing my own plaq mounts.  What is the equipment and process involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following article after a good hour of searching around. There are a zillion places that offer to do plaq/block/artblock mounting for you, but this was the only one I could find that actually explained the process:

[How to Plaque Mount Posters using MDF](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-plaque-mount-posters-using-mdf-082397/)

Hope its helpful.

Comment: It's better than nothing - I think my frame place uses heat activated adhesive and laminate; that process requires a press.

Answer (score 0):

This is going back a lot of years, but my grandfather did this using wood and polyurethane, but that was with film-based prints. I'm not entirely sure if the same process would work with prints from an inkjet printer, but you could try it with a small sample, just give it a lengthy time to dry thoroughly (at least 24 hours).

Comment: I do believe this kind of mount works for digital prints, as I have purchased Giclée art block prints from DeviantArt.com. I am not certain how, exactly, they do the mounting, but the Giclée printing process is a high quality ink jet on satin printing process.

Comment: @jrista I'm familiar with the lab DA uses, their mounted Giclée is spray adhesive... one of the 3M Super Spray versions (77 or 72 I think) on the back of the print and the face of the wood, then under a roller to adhere them and left to cure, there is an optional spray coating, but it's a very thin one, and is for protection/gloss, not mounting.

Comment: The old wood and poly process John's talking about is pretty different, it involves placing the paper on the face of the wood, usually with a noticeable amount of wood showing around it, then covering the whole thing with poly, usually pretty thick. If you're familiar with decoupage, you can almost think of this as a heavy version of that. (My mother and I mounted a lot of poetry that way back in the day.)